# Behavior of a C program using fork()

Tags: c, process, fork

Given the following code, I have to check its behavior, that is, how much processes are produced.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int pid, i , j;
    pid_t t;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }

    printf("I am the process %d and my father is the process %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    while(wait(NULL)>0) {}

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling and executing, the output is as follows:

```
I am the process 3749 and my father is the process 2254

I am the process 3750 and my father is the process 3749

I am the process 3751 and my father is the process 3749

I am the process 3752 and my father is the process 3749

I am the process 3754 and my father is the process 3749

I am the process 3753 and my father is the process 3750

I am the process 3755 and my father is the process 3750

I am the process 3756 and my father is the process 3752

I am the process 3757 and my father is the process 3752

I am the process 3758 and my father is the process 3756

I am the process 3759 and my father is the process 3756
```

This means the corresponding tree process looks like this:

```
                      2254
                       |
                   -- 3749 ----
                  /   |   \    \
                3750 3751 3752 3754
               /   \      /  \
            3753  3755  3756 3757
                       /   \
                     3758  3759
```

In total, 11 processes are produced, if we count the initial process.

I expected much more processes to be generated than just 11; anyway, I am able to understand the spawning of all processes but the most distant leaves (3758 and 3759).

In the program there are two for loops, being one nested into the other. As two break statements are inside each loop, I guess that a loop or the two should finish at some point before their natural end.

Could somebody confirm this code's behavior?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I see 12 processes in your excellent tree diagram of processes.  Did you mean 12 instead of 11?

Comment: Yes @Edwin Buck I meant 12 processes if we count the father of the initial process. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of programs are more to illustrate that you understand how forking works, I hope you never write a forking program within multiple nested loops complete with breaks.

They way you track this is by simulating the machine on paper, but each time you simulate the fork, you copy the simulation, setting the return code of `fork()` for one copy to zero, and the return code of the other copy to the other process's pid.

Let me reformat your program to make it easier

```
    int pid;
    int i;
    int j;
    pid_t t;
```

will hold our "current values" for a process.  We will also indicate the instruction pointer location with "IP ==>"

```
    int pid;
    int i;
    int j;
    pid_t t;
    IP ===>
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

Next step (for PID 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid;
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j;
    pid_t t;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    IP ===>
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PID 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1  // fake pid, but easy to count)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j;
    pid_t t;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
    IP ===>
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for process 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
    IP ===>
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PID 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 2, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 2, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
   IP ===>
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PID 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 2, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 2, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  
   IP ===>
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 3, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  
                t = fork();
   IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  
                t = fork();
   IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 3, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
    IP ===>
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  
                t = fork();
    IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int pid = 1;
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 1, due to j++)
    pid_t t; (set to 3, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())  // pid == 1, getpid == 1. so skip break
            break;
    IP ===>
    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
    IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int pid = 1;
    int i; (set to 1)
    int j; (set to 1, due to j++)
    pid_t t; (set to 3, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; IP ===> i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())  // pid == 1, getpid == 1. so skip break
            break;

    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
    IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int pid = 1;
    int i; (set to 1)
    int j; (set to 1, due to j++)
    pid_t t; (set to 3, parent process)

    for (i = 0; IP ===> i < 2;  i++) { // 1 is less than 2 so enter loop block
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())  // pid == 1, getpid == 1. so skip break
            break;

    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
    IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int pid = 1;
    int i; (set to 1)
    int j; (set to 1)
    pid_t t; (set to 3, parent process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2;  i++) {
    IP ===>
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())  // pid == 1, getpid == 1. so skip break
            break;

    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
    IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1, again)
    int pid = 1;
    int i; (set to 1)
    int j; (set to 1)
    pid_t t; (set to 3)

    for (i = 0; i < 2;  i++) {
        pid = getpid();
    IP ===>
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())  // pid == 1, getpid == 1. so skip break
            break;

    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
    IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

next step (for PROCESS 1)

```
    === PROCESS 1 ====
    int pid (set to 1)
    int pid = 1;
    int i; (set to 1)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 3)

    for (i = 0; i < 2;  i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
    IP ===>
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())  // pid == 1, getpid == 1. so skip break
            break;

    }
    === PROCESS 2 ===
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child process)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
    IP ===>
            if (t != 0) {
                t = fork();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
    === PROCESS 3 ====
    int i; (set to 0)
    int j; (set to 0)
    pid_t t; (set to 0, child of PID 1)

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = getpid();
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            t = fork();
            if (t != 0) {  // t == 2 in this process, so enter the block
                t = fork();
    IP ===>
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            break;
    }
```

And so on.  Once you get Process 1 out of it's loops (and waiting for its children complete), you follow the same procedure for Process 2 until it is out of it's loops and waiting for it's children to complete.

The point of this exercise is if you can simulate some confusing process code.  It is clear that since the top level process will loop twice, and it never breaks out of the loop, you will get 4 processes under it.  As you practice stepping through the other processes, you will start to see the patterns they implement.

Personally, this kind of problem is a lot of work, and not the kind of work that makes you a better programmer; but, it will demonstrate if you understand that a program is forked with it's current state (notice that pid is wrong in many of the children, because it wasn't updated after the fork), and if you understand that fully, you can simulate the program to it's final completion.

Of course, we use computers to automate boring stuff (like this), so you might want to come up with a new logging line like this:

```
 void printState(int me, int pid, int i, int j, int t) {
     printf("PID %d: pid = %d, i = %d, j = %d, t = %d\n");
 }
```

and then run

```
   printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
   for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
        pid = getpid();
        printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
        for (j = 0 ; j < i+2; j++){
            printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
            t = fork();
            printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
            if (t != 0) {
                printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
                t = fork();
                printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pid != getpid())
            printState(getpid(), pid, i, j, t);
            break;
    }
```

and collect the output, ordering them by their self-reported pid numbers (getpid(), not pid variable)

Comment: Thank you a lot @Edwin Buck for your great answer.

Comment: As I said, I understand most of the process creation but I don't still see the point of the two outermost processes or leaves created (#3758 and #3759 in my process tree). The inner loop applies two times fork(), being the first one a general fork() and the second one only meant to father processes. The two outermost leaves are created according to the inner loop pattern but why not the rest of the grandchild processes do not spawn leaves too? Thank you

Comment: @The_Student There is a difference between understanding how fork works and simulating the processes above.  Only simulating the processes above correctly will fully explain why those last processes were created.  I imagine that you simulated some of this, but not the whole thing, and you are making logical guesses which cover many (if not most) of the processes.  Please provide more detail other than "show me" and I can help review for mistakes (or at least understand your problem better).

Comment: Exactly @Edwin Buck, only by tracking every process is how you can figure out the whole thing. I've made a process tree with all the i's and j's and yes, 11 processes are produced and the two most external leaves are generated by i = 1 and j = 2 (they're the only processes which fulfill that condition). Your answer was decisive for helping me to simulate the whole code. Thank you a lot again. Regards

Comment: I'll post the mentioned process tree soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process creation procedure based on the program's simulation explained by @Edwin Buck (thank you Edwin!)

```
                    1
                    |
               ---- 2 -----
              /   /   \    \
             3   4     5    6
           /   \      /  \
          7     8    9   10
                   /   \
                  11   12
```

Process #1: Initial process's father.

Process #2: Initial process. It's the only process which fulfills pid = getpid().

Process #3: Spawned at i = 0, j = 0.

Process #4: Spawned at i = 0, j = 0.

Process #7: Spawned at i = 0, j = 1.

Process #8: Spawned at i = 0, j = 1.

Process #5: Spawned at i = 1, j = 0.

Process #6: Spawned at i = 1, j = 0.

Process #9: Spawned at i = 1, j = 1.

Process #10: Spawned at i = 1, j = 1.

Process #11: Spawned at i = 1, j = 2.

Process #12: Spawned at i = 1, j = 2.